# How to time each command within a bash script (Running a Series of psql statements)

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, psql

I currently have a bash script that runs a bunch of psql scripts. These psql scripts look like:

```
psql -a -f "filename.sql"
psql -a -f "filename2.sql"
etc.
```

So each `psql` is executing PostgreSQL stored in different files. I am running a series of them in a bash script, and it would be helpful for me to know how long each file is taking.

A hacky way I thought of doing this is to just print `date` before and after each one (i.e.)

```
date
psql -a -f "filename.sql"
date

psql -a -f "filename2.sql"
date
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `time` command. See the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)

```
time psql -a -f "filename1.sql"
... # et cetera
```

It runs your command and has time output, such as

```sh
real    0m33.961s
user    0m0.340s
sys     0m0.940s
```

Answer (score 0):

For more resolution, **change your `sql` scripts** like this, which will time the individual `sql` statements inside the scripts:

```
\timing on
-- some sql statements that you want to benchmark
\timing off
```

If you simply add `\timing on` at the top of the `sql` script, all statements in the script will be benchmarked.

From [`psql` manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> `\timing [ on | off ]`
> With a parameter, turns displaying of how long
> each SQL statement takes on or off. Without a parameter, toggles the
> display between on and off. The display is in milliseconds; intervals
> longer than 1 second are also shown in minutes:seconds format, with
> hours and days fields added if needed.